# convert grouplens dataset to csv file using java

Tags: java, csv

I have a dataset file-> u.item where

```
u.item     -- Information about the items (movies); this is a tab separated
          list of
          movie id | movie title | release date | video release date |
          IMDb URL | unknown | Action | Adventure | Animation |
          Children's | Comedy | Crime | Documentary | Drama | Fantasy |
          Film-Noir | Horror | Musical | Mystery | Romance | Sci-Fi |
          Thriller | War | Western |
          The last 19 fields are the genres, a 1 indicates the movie
          is of that genre, a 0 indicates it is not; movies can be in
          several genres at once.
          The movie ids are the ones used in the u.data data set.
```

To process it in my java application i need to convert it into  csv format, where I require only movie_id and movie_name.

I am writing the java code to convert it into csv as

```
 package com.convert;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;


 public class MovieDataConvert { 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/u.item"));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new    FileWriter("data/moviesItem.csv"));

        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] values = line.split("\\t", -1);
        bw.write(values[0] + "," + values[1]  +  "\n");
    }

    br.close();
    bw.close();

}
```

}

But I am getting the following error

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at com.convert.MovieDataConvert.main(MovieDataConvert.java:18)
```

What I am doing wrong?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJauI.jpg)

Comment: It looks like u.item is not a tab separated list but '|' separated. Try it with 
String[] values = line.split("\\|", -1);

Comment: Great, that worked. Thanks